# CAShapeLayer Animating Path Glitches / Flickers (From Ellipse to Rect and back)

Tags: ios, core-animation, cgpath, cabasicanimation

I am running into an issue when I create an explicit animation to change the value of a CAShapeLayer's path from an ellipse to a rect.

In my canvas controller I setup a basic CAShapeLayer and add it to the root view's layer:

```
CAShapeLayer *aLayer;
aLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
aLayer.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(aLayer.frame, nil);
aLayer.lineWidth = 10.0f;
aLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
aLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:aLayer];
```

Then, when I animate the path I get a strange glitch / flicker in the last few frames of the animation when the shape becomes a rect, and in the first few frames when it animates away from being a rect. The animation is set up as follows:

```
CGPathRef newPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(aLayer.frame, nil);
[CATransaction lock];
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:5.0f];
CABasicAnimation *ba = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
ba.autoreverses = YES;
ba.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
ba.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
ba.fromValue = (id)aLayer.path;
ba.toValue = (__bridge id)newPath;
[aLayer addAnimation:ba forKey:@"animatePath"];
[CATransaction commit];
[CATransaction unlock];
```

I have tried many different things like locking / unlocking the CATransaction, playing with various fill modes, etc...

Here's an image of the glitch:
http://www.postfl.com/outgoing/renderingglitch.png

A video of what I am experiencing can be found here:
http://vimeo.com/37720876

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a limitation of the otherwise awesome animatable path property of CAShapeLayers.

Basically it tries to interpolate between the two paths. It hits trouble when the destination path and start path have a different number of control points - and curves and straight edges will have this problem.

You can try to minimise the effect by drawing your ellipse as 4 curves instead of a single ellipse, but it still isn't quite right.  I haven't found a way to go smoothly from curves to polygons.

You may be able to get most of the way there, then transfer to a fade animation for the last part - this won't look as nice, though.

Comment: Between your answer and the one I posted from David Duncan, I have a pretty good sense of what's going on. Hopefully the animatable path property gets better in future releases.

Comment: If you do work it out using the arc rectangles approach, please post it here!

Comment: I don't know if you've worked on this, or seen any good answers since this post was made. I'm starting to work on a general circle to polygon animation, and currently have it working for a circle to square animation. I've posted that code as an answer to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437014/animating-between-two-bezier-path-shapes/28448397#28448397

Comment: @rdelmar no I haven't worked on this for a while. It ought to be easier than it is...

Answer (score 8):

I received this feedback from the quartz-dev list:

David Duncan wrote:

> Animating the path of a shape layer is only guaranteed to work when
>   you are animating from like to like. A rectangle is a sequence of
>   lines, while an ellipse is a sequence of arcs (you can see the
>   sequence generated by using CGPathApply), and as such the animation
>   between them isn't guaranteed to look very good, or work well at all.
>
> To do this, you basically have to create an analog of a rectangle by
>   using the same curves that you would use to create an ellipse, but
>   with parameters that would cause the rendering to look like a
>   rectangle. This shouldn't be too difficult (and again, you can use
>   what you get from CGPathApply on the path created with
>   CGPathAddEllipseInRect as a guide), but will likely require some
>   tweaking to get right.